# How much can I trust OracleDB's ROWID in a long run?

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot

I am working on a small POC using Spring Boot and OracleDB.

The situation is :

While application startup, I load few properties (some data) from the DB in the cache. There are going to be frequent request where I will be needing this data, hence I decided to cache it. The data in the DB will rarely change. Only once in a while some one can insert/delete/update a couple of rows using the sql script. While it changes, I have implemented Oracle's [DB change notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28819) to send notification to the spring boot service that some data has changed and the data in the cache is is now in the stale state.

In the notification event, I only get the [ROWID pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns008.htm#SQLRF00254) which can be used to point to what portion of data from the db is different from the cache that I have. To be on the safer side, I have decided to cache ROWIDs to map the data in cache and data object in the notification event that DB sends me. While working for a couple of days, I have found out that the ROWID doesn't change but how much shall I trust this non-changing behavior of the ROWIDs in the long run or in the production environment?

Few Scenarios explained for clarification:

1. Cache will reload itself every time the server restarts. Therefore, data change while the server is down situation is out of picture.
2. I am (up until the poc) getting every insert/update/delete notification in the made in the db using the sql query/script.

Example of event.toString() for reference:

```
Connection information  : local=view-localhost/127.0.0.1:47632, remote=view-localhost/127.0.0.1:57117
Registration ID         : 1201
Notification version    : 1
Event type              : QUERYCHANGE
Database name           : orcl
Query Change Description (length=1)
  query ID=41, query change event type=QUERYCHANGE
  Table Change Description (length=1):    operation=[INSERT], tableName=SYSTEM.PRODUCT, objectNumber=73323
    Row Change Description (length=1):
      ROW:  operation=INSERT, ROWID=AAAR5rAABAAAbHZAAA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table does not have `row_movement` enabled (check `dba_tables`).

You need to be careful of deletes then inserts - these will logically give a row a new rowid (it’s a completely new row after all).
You also will need to be aware of table moves, this is an intensive operation that requires indexes are rebuilt anyway so is unlikely to happen without much notice.

Otherwise, a row will keep it’s rowid.